# Detect when any dialog opens jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dialog

I have several dialogs that open like this

```
 $("#dialog").load(URL);
 $("#dialog").dialog(
           attributes,
           here,
           close: function(e,u) {
                    cleanup
           }
```

The issue is that I have hundreds of these dialogs.  I do not want to manually have to create an open: attribute for each one.  Is there any way I can monitor the entire document for a dialog open such as

```
 $(document).on("open","#dialog",function() {
     Do something
 })
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a `class` for the dialog and check bacsed on the `class`

Comment: You'd want to use a class attribute rather than an id attribute.

Comment: Assuming <div id="dialog"></div> did have a class such as <div id="dialog" class="dialogClass"></div>, how can I check if it's open?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From jQuery API:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

So you could do what you said probably:

```
$("body").on("dialogopen",function(e,u){
    alert('dialog open!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dialogs are always created the same way, why not using a simple factory method like this :

```
var createUrlDialog = function(element, url, dialogOptions) {
    element.load(url);
    element.dialog($.extend({}, dialogOptions, {
        open: function(event, ui) {
            // do what you want
        }
    }));
}
```